# CSS overlapping in reactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

in my react project, in the **SRC** directory I have **components** directory, which contains components folders, every component folder has react component (JSX) and a CSS file, I found that the CSS styles in a component folder overlap with other components styles, although I'm only importing it in the JSX file that I want to use the styles for, why is that happening? like I want to have a CSS file for every component separately

Answer (score 1):

Do you have experience in pure HTML, CSS, and JS before? CSS rules are global.

The closest to what you are looking for is CSS module, if you are using Create React App, it is supported out of the box.

Comment: in pure HTML, CSS, and JS.. styles will only apply if you link the CSS file, like if an element in 2 html files has the same class, and one of these files is linked to CSS file while the other is not, the styles will not overlap until you link the other file to the same CSS file, not sure what do you mean by "CSS rules are global", but thanks.. i used the CSS module and it works fine

Comment: Actually, by importing the CSS files, you are merely telling to bundler to include those CSS files when you build the website.  That means the CSS file you imported in `ComponentA` will actually affect the entire application. If you managed to have duplicated IDs and class names across the application, the CSS rules with overwrite each other even if it is only imported in one component

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day all your styles are compiled into a global stylesheet, specifically in multiple style tags spread across the application which are scoped to the global app.

If you need to scope styles to components, you need to use something like [styled components](https://styled-components.com/).

Take a look at this post that might help you understand it better.
https://blog.logrocket.com/styling-in-react-4-ways-style-react-app/